# How do you flexibly retain useful object functionality between the usage and definition of a method?

Tags: java, subclass

#### Exposition:

Suppose I have this trivial interface:

```
interface Y { Y f(); }
```

I can implement it in 3 different ways:

1. Use the general type everywhere.

   ```
   class SubY_generalist implements Y
   {
       public Y f()
       {
           Y y = new SubY_generalist();
           ...
           return y;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use the special type, but return the same value implicitly cast into general type.

   ```
   class SubY_mix implements Y
   {
       public Y f()
       {
           SubY_mix y = new SubY_mix();
           ...
           return y;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use the special type and return it the same.

   ```
   class SubY_specialist implements Y
   {
       public SubY_specialist f()
       {
           SubY_specialist y = new SubY_specialist();
           ...
           return y;
       }
   }
   ```

#### My considerations:

There is a [lengthy conversation nearby here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) on the benefits of *"programming to an
interface"*. The most promoted answers do not seem to go deep into the distinction between
argument and return types, which are in fact [fundamentally distinct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)). Finding therefore that
the discussion elsewhere does not provide me with a clean-cut answer, I have no choice but to
speculate on it by myself — unless the kind reader can lend me a hand, of course.

I will assume the following basic facts about Java: *(Are they correct?)*

1. An object is created at its most special.
2. It may be implicitly cast into a more general type *(generalized)* at any time.
3. When an object is generalized, it loses some of its useful properties, but gains none.

From these simple points, it follows that a special object is more useful, but also more dangerous
than the general.

As an example, I may have a mutable container that I can generalize into being
immutable. If I ensure the container has some useful properties before being thus frozen, I can
generalize it at the right time to prevent the user from accidentally breaking the invariant. But
is this the right way? There is another way to achieve similar isolation: I may always just make
my methods *package-private*. Generalizing seems to be more flexible but easy to omiss and
introduce a surface for subtle bugs.

But in some languages, like Python, it is deemed unnecessary to ever actually protect methods from
outside access; they just label the internal methods with an underscore. A proficient user may
access the internal methods to achieve some gain, provided that they know all the intricacies.

Another consequence is that inside the method definitions I should prefer specialized objects.

#### My questions:

- Is this right thinking?
- Am I missing something?
- How does this relate to the talk of *programming to an interface*? Some locals here seem to
  think it is relevant, and I agree that it does, just not immediately, as I see it. It is more
  like *programming against an interface* here, or *against a subclass* in general. I am a bit at
  a loss about these intricacies.

Comment: You should always do choice 1 if you can, because that makes your code more flexible. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: What about `List<Y>` vs. `List<SubY>`? The first list would store every object that implements `Y` while the second one would only store instances of `SubY` (less flexible). Hint: `List<Y> ys = new ArrayList<>();` where `ArrayList<E> implements List<E>`.

Comment: @Sweeper I do not believe you. See extended answer.

Comment: @Sweeper Actually I believe you, if by "first" you mean the subclass. At first I thought you refer to items in order of their appearance in the code fragments.

Comment: @Sweeper Actually if you are saying "choice 1", it is justified to think that you are talking about code fragments. Then we are not on the same page. Your comment is ambiguous, I cannot make definite sense of it.

Comment: I'd claim this is not a duplicate of [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) on the following basis: Asking about "Programming to an interface" is answered by the concept of programming to an interface. This question is more about the following design decision: "How do you retain useful properties of objects for a function when the caller or implementer might "program to an interface"?"

Comment: @Avi I appreciate your support.

Comment: @Avi can you help me formulate the same without referring to that _"programming to an interface"_ catchphrase? I am not yet at terms with it.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov Perhaps, "How do you flexibly retain useful object functionality between the usage and definition of a function?"

Comment: @Avi _"...of a method"_, but otherwise yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the context I'm using to talk about the topic. Let there be the following options for a function f:

```
interface Y { ... }
class SubY implements Y { ... }
DEFINITION CHOICE:
public SubY f() { ... }
OR
public Y f() { ... }
USAGE CHOICE:
...
Y y = f();
OR
SubY y = f(); //maybe with a cast
...
```

Technically, all options can be correct, depending on whether you intend to expose the details of `SubY` to the end-user (next programmer) or not. If it looks like a bad idea to expose `SubY` to the end-user, don't. Otherwise, do. Here's the reasoning:
     You should always return the narrowest type that could be needed, conceptually (narrower types are further down the [class hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_hierarchy) - treat it as "a narrower type is-a wider type"). For example, if you return a `List`, that means that you expect the end-user to interact with it only in terms of an interface. However, if you expect that the end-user will need the interactions defined within `ArrayList`, return that instead.
     In general, the idea is to keeps the return type from methods as narrow as possible, without exposing gory details that the end-user shouldn't be aware of. As long as you properly hide the internal details handled by your class `SubY`, it is perfectly fine to return a `SubY`. On the other hand, consider the responsibility of the end-user:
     The responsibilty of the end-user is to responsibly use the power they've been given by your narrow return type. You have already prevented them from doing nasty things by hiding internals properly. Then, when the end-user uses your class, they should program in terms of their needs, like so:

```
// imported library provides:
public SubY f() { ... }
... // la la la
Y y = f();
useYFunctionality(y);
... // somewhere else that you need SubY functionality
SubY subY = f();
useSubYFunctionality(subY);
```

Therefore, the programmer should define their functions to return precise types, returning the narrowest possible implementation that is safe (it *can* be an interface). On the other hand, the end-user of that service/functionality should define their variables as the widest possible type that still works, to decrease coupling and increase clarity of intent (if `getLicensePlateNumber` is all you need, use `Vehicle` instead of `VeryUnreliableCar`). The key here is that choosing the return type doesn't have a *definite* answer. Instead, use your judgment to decide what should and should not be exposed to the end-user. If there's no exceptional reason to deny access to `SubY`, then keep this principle in mind: `Functions Return Accurately, Users Define Variables As Necessary`, or FRAUDVAN.
     Applying this to your examples:

```
class SubY_generalist implements Y
{
    public Y f()
    {
        Y y = new SubY_generalist();
        ...
        return y;
    }
}
```

1. Using the interface everywhere. This is best when you only care about the details of the interface, and the same holds true for the end-user. For example, if you only care about `get` and `add`, `Y` could be `List`, and `SubY_generalist()` could be `ArrayList`.

```
class SubY_mix implements Y
{
    public Y f()
    {
        SubY_mix y = new SubY_mix();
        ...
        return y;
    }
}
```

2. Using the specific type, but implicitly widening into the general type at return. This is best when you actually need to use methods for the specific type, but your end-user will *never* need to do so. Using `ArrayList` and `List` from the previous example, suppose `f` must invoke `trimToSize`, a method not defined in `List`. Then, it's clearly necessary to declare `y` as `ArrayList`. However, since the end-user only needs the `List`, you should return `y` and implicitly widen.

```
class SubY_specialist implements Y
{
    public SubY_specialist f()
    {
        SubY_specialist y = new SubY_specialist();
        ...
        return y;
    }
}
```

3. Using the specialized type, and returning the specialized type. This is the "essence" of FRAUDVAN. `SubY_specialist` as the return type allows the user the flexibility to deal with the `SubY_specialist` returned, or alternatively use `f()` in terms of the interface `Y`. This is *incredibly common*, when interfaces are insufficiently specific to be used effectively (as they should be, since they're *abstract*). For example, in the Java [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) class, any time a method returns a `Stream`, this is happening. This is because `Stream` implements [`BaseStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html). It *also* happens any time you take a `StringBuffer` and `reverse`, `append`, `replace`, `delete`, or `insert` (`StringBuffer` implements `CharSequence`).
       The reason this kind of behavior is needed is that interfaces often don't contain enough details to be utilized effectively by the end-user. Putting those details in interfaces would result in interface bloat/pollution, which is undesirable. Instead, directly having the class responsible for those details be used preserves the single responsibility principle for classes that have unique functionalities (avoiding being forced to implement redundancy in future implementers of the interface). After all, if your class implements two interfaces, you either have to create a new interface extending both those interfaces and return that (which can get ugly pretty quickly), or you can return the implementor, and have the end-user be responsible for which interface they need (not ugly).
       Why is this kind of behavior so common? It's because, once you hide away things that end-users don't need to see (using visibility modifiers, encapsulation, and information hiding), it's actually a *good idea* to let end-users interact with your implementations in the manner that they choose (i.e. as per the interface they declare their variable as). In fact, I'd even claim that all examples here are compliant to FRAUDVAN, where the "safest" type to expose to the user is `Y` instead of a specialized type. In the first example, the interface `Y` is sufficiently specialized for the user and the end-users. In the second example, `Y` is insufficiently specialized for the user, but sufficiently specialized for the end-users. Finally, in this example, `Y` is insufficiently specialized for the user and all end-users, although some end-users may choose to declare `Y y = f()` if `Y` will suit their needs.

So, here's the take away:
[image: FRAUDVAN]

Comment: P.S. I use "function"/"method" interchangeably here to describe a piece of code that performs a task (possibly with some return value), but technically, Java only has methods.

Comment: Also, what is this yellow/red thingie on the bus?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov A strobe light. Also, it's FRAUDVAN, not fraud bus